# Python plugin for netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, python, plugins, netbeans, jython

I need to add python plugin for NetBeans 8.2 but I am unable to find the plugins anywhere, I've tried searching some blogs and website

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/python-in-netbeans-ide-802

but the websites(https://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/56795?show=true) they've referred are not working,

could anyone please help me how to get the plugins

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should come with NetBeans after 8.1. Did you check if it is already in Tools > Plugins?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes I have checked in the Available plugins there was nothing related to python plugins.

Comment: @Selcuk I don't believe NetBeans 8.2 came with a Python plugin. It's certainly not there on my 8.2 installation.

Comment: This a comment, not a solution. [1] You are linking to an article that is over six years old. NetBeans 8.2 is no longer supported, and Python plugins were never _officially_ supported either. [2] In addition to that, several Update Centers that provided NetBeans 8.2 plugins, such as `http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/8.2/catalog.xml.gz` are no longer accessible. [3] There was an effort to create a Plugin for Apache NetBeans named [NBPthon](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/NBPython), but it looks like it was never implemented....

Comment: ...Given all that, your best hope might be to find an "unofficial" location where you can download the old plugin to get Python working on NetBeans 8.2. But if it is feasible, perhaps it just makes more sense to use another IDE such as Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA or PyCharm where Python is actively supported?